# Accessing /system in android

Tags: android

i want my app to run as root and access /system folder. I want to access the build.prop file. I've tried and got su permissions but i'm unable to know how to read/write files in the / folder. Please help

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, an app like that would only be able to do it on a rooted phone

Comment: my phone is rooted and im testing the app on my phone

Comment: Even on a rooted phone, applications cannot run as root, they can only run helper processes as root.  The mechanisms (and debatable wisdom) of doing this has been covered here many times.

Answer (score 0):

install ES File Explore..in that go to settings and turn on Root.After that one Popup will appear in that slecect second one and turn it on.!Thats it..!Now in the top,select Devices to see your system files.So,You can Modify it..!system/build-prp